# Is there a special form of UPDATE statement that does nothing but checks as valid SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 2 columns (both integer) and the primary key consists of both of these columns. My application does not execute an UPDATE statement on this table and I am using PostgreSQL.

But my application creates INSERT,DELETE and UPDATE prepared statements for all the tables by using the particular table info in advance. For this specific table, WHERE clause for the UPDATE statement contains these 2 columns but SET clause is empty, which causes an error.

**Is there a special form of UPDATE statement that does nothing but checks as valid SQL ?**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `update foo set bar = 42 where false`

Comment: what about update foo set bar=bar

Comment: @Mina: Thanks Mina, as simple as it gets. This worked OK for me...

Comment: Add where false too! (Transactions...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A statement like this one is the wrong choice. Don't do this.

```
update foo set bar = bar;
```

Although the underlying data doesn't seem to change, PostgreSQL actually performs the update, along with all its side effects. Side effects might include these.

- The update affects an undetermined number of rows.
- Writes to the transaction log. (Might write a *lot*.)
- Fires triggers.
- Enforces foreign key constraints, possibly cascading updates.

Use `WHERE FALSE` to check for errors.

```
update foo set bar = bar where false;
```

Simple tests will show that no update takes place, no triggers fire, etc.

The execution plans for those two queries are radically different. Inspect with `explain analyze`.

Comment: _"The update affects an undetermined number of rows"_
Number is determined by your `where` condition that you should use with almost each update (except of eg. data migration).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `EXPLAIN UPDATE` which returns a query plan for a valid statement but an error if the statement is not valid.

Comment: All the SQL text generation is done by code. This is something I will save for later. Thanks...